# Can't access Synapse Studio

Tags: azure-synapse

I am trying to access Synapse Studio  here https://web.azuresynapse.net

and I get the below message
[image]

Could it be access related?

Comment: More likely that its firewall related. Can you access other Azure resources? Also try on another computer\network if you can

Comment: please try with below options 1.Clear “Cookies and Cached data” of your browser. 2.Private Mode (New InPrivate Window). 3.Try in different browser.

Comment: I agree with the firewall notion. In the Azure Portal, go to the Synapse instance > Networking and make sure your IP address is cleared for access.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @Chen Hirsh and @Joel Cochran It can be access related issue of network.

**To resolve this try below options:**

1. Go to synapse workspace on your Azure Portal >> Networking >> Add Client IP and make sure your IP address has the access to the workspace.
   [image]
2. Clear “**Cookies and Cached data**” of your browser.
3. Try with Private Mode (New InPrivate Window).
4. Try in different browser.